# How do I turn string insert data into a series for react highcharts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

This is a straight forward question that's a little tricky to explain if you don't know highcharts.  So, with a simple  block lets say I want to write `

```
[{"name":"Name1","data":[{"x":1477621800,"y":114,"name":"Name2"}]`
```

to insert into my highcharts series.
How do I do insert this into the series?  I've tried JSON.parse() but it doesn't work....

Basically,  I want to dynamically add data through an input field.

Answer (score 0):

> `I've tried JSON.parse() but it doesn't work....`

That's logical. You are missing `}]` at the end of the string.

That's why it "doesn't work".

`[{"name":"Name1","data":[{"x":1477621800,"y":114,"name":"Name2"}]`

There are 2 `[` and `{`, but there are only 1 `}` and `]`.

Try using:

```
JSON.parse(`[{"name":"Name1","data":[{"x":1477621800,"y":114,"name":"Name2"}]}]`)
```